# How to resolve #NAME? error in Excel?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm use Excel 2003. There is numeric information in Cell AI in my Spreadsheet. The cell is formatted as numeric with 4 decimal places. In Cell AK, which is also formatted as numeric, I type `=AI` and get `#NAME?` error.

What can I do to resolve problem?

Comment: Cell AI doesnt make sense, it should be alphanumetic, not just alphabets

Answer (score 1):

If Excel can't understand the reference or the formula you have entered then it gives you the #NAME? error. In your case `=AI` doesn't refer to a real cell, it looks like you meant to enter `=A1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell is parhaps A1? It's not working because your using 2 letters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem and I got the expected results; the value for the cell with the name **AI** appeared when I entered the formula `=AI`.

If you're getting the #NAME? error, it most likely means that there is no cell or range of cells with the name **AI**.
This can be easily resolved by ensuring there is a valid cell/range with the name.

If you still have the problem, try naming your cell to something that actually represents the content of the cell. If that is not possible, append an underscore to the name (`AI_`) and use it in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference the row too.
The data may be in column `AI` but it also has a row, else excel wouldn't know which cell in AI to select.

Instead of typing =AI, type =, then use cursor keys to get to the cell with your data

Comment: How do you get a row AI in Excel 2003?